# Upload large files from SharePoint to Azure Blob

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, blob, logic-app

What I want to accomplish.

1. Each user can upload large xml files (4mb to 2000mb) to a SharePoint document library. Only the user and the admin can see their files. (critical that they dont see each others files)
2. Verify the xml file
3. Upload to a Azure blob storage
4. File in SharePoint gets deleted

My plan

1. Create an simple spfx webpart that can copy a file to a spesific document library in SharePoint. I could turn on version control on the files so the user will only show their own drafted files. Or I could break inherance and set read only to a spesific user. (?)
2. Create a logic app that fires when a new file is uploaded to SharePoint that creates an Azure Functions that verify and upload the file to Azure blob using clientid and secret.
3. When completed delte file in SharePoint

Is this a good approach? Will there be any issues validating files against blob or should I do that in the "SharePoint context"? If you know a better way to directly upload the file from SharePoint to azure blob please show me an example :)

I´ve tried:

- Logic app that upload file to azure blob. Seems ot be a problem with files > 100 MB

Answer (score 0):

You can sharepoint rest api along with azure function app for transferring large files. You should use small byte arrays to so that you won’t run out of memory. If you are using a trigger in logic app, you will need to used dountill step in logic app to make sure the file is completely uploaded since the sharepoint trigger gets triggered even before file is created